# How do I add a file from my local machine to a local git repository that I have cloned?

Tags: git

I really have two related questions.  Note that my OS is Windows 10.

1. Say I have cloned a github repository onto my local machine in path `C:\Users\<user>\<cloned-repository>`.  I have a file on my local machine in path `C:\Users\<user>\<folder>\<project>\<filename>` that I want to add to the repository.  How would I do this from the command line?
2. How can I take a file from a cloned repository, edit it in an editor of my choice (instead of just using vim), and commit/push changes I made back to the repository?

Comment: Have you read the [git tutorial](https://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial)?

Comment: Yeah I've looked at several actually but for some reason the relationship between one's local machine and one's local repository wasn't clicking in my brain correctly.  Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could switch working-tree just for one command:

```
cd /path/to/cloned/repo
git --work-tree=c:\Users\<user>\<folder>\<project> add filename
git commit -m "Add filename"
```

You can edit any file you want with the IDE/editor of your choosing.